# Golang + ajax post data

Tags: jquery, ajax, go

I've got a page with a number of fields, not in a form setup because I wanna be able to act on them individually and post with ajax. I am using Go to process the post data. However, it seems to post multiple times because in my Go code I am outputting a post variable to the console to test, and it dumps the output 5 times, which represents the number of variables in the post data. I also had this type of behavior when I just used a jquery alert to show the post data. Am I misunderstanding something about how ajax posts, or is there some other bug going on?

### Go code

```
func addProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {

              frmCategory:=r.PostFormValue("category")
              fmt.Println(frmCategory)
}

func main() {

          router:=httprouter.New()
          router.POST("/addProduct",addProduct)

}
```

### AJAX code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

var postData="bcode\="+ $('#bCodeID').val()+"&category\="+$("#selected_category").val()+"&price\="+priceModifier+"&description\="+$('#itemDescription').val()+"&colorcode\="+$('#SelectedColorCode').val();

$.ajax({

        url: '/addProduct',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'text',
        data : postData,
        success : function(data) {
              $('#warningBox').modal({
                  show: false
              });
        }
});
```

### Console output

```
Toys

Toys

Toys

Toys

Toys

Toys

Toys
```

Comment: Update. For some odd reason other items on the page fail to respond after the page is loaded, until at least one of them is clicked 2 times. After one element (a button, dropdown, etc) is clicked twice, everything else begins to respond.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug. Earlier I was experimenting with not allowing clicks outside of a modal dialog, and was using $(document).click(function () { ... } wrapped around all my jscript code. Once I removed that, everything else fixed itself.